# Getting on, on the trend train - Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> My first is fruit,
>   last is knuckle substitute,
>   middle one is space so small,
>   but I am ignorant overall.

note : OnlyF got the first part correct

(The final word does not have any abbreviation or short cut, it uses word as it is )

Hint :

> me and my friend were playing the "guess me game" : this is how questioning (and answering) went :
>
> umm... fruit  :  yes
>   easily available fruit?  : yes
>   related to home? : In a way, yes
>   what about drinks? : Yaasss
>   Daiquiri?? : no
>   martini?? : no, but close
>   superhero?  : yes
>   from DC?  : no
>   marvel then? : nope

Comment: You state that Shane Hsu got the first part correct, and that the final word will not use abbreviations.  But Shane Hsu's guess for the first part is an abbreviation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pugmonkey sorry, my bad corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess:

> Apple-knocker

We already know the fruit is

> apple.

The knuckle substitute refers to

> a "[knocker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BHSRJMQ)": object that can be used to knock on a door instead of rapping with one's knuckles (also related to home, as in the clue).

The space so small now needs to be

> small space between the words joined by the hyphen. Alternatively, spell it without the hyphen and let the infix be "nock" - a small groove in a bow/arrow.

Giving our word, which

> [apparently](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apple-knocker) means an ignorant person. Also to address the hint: [apple knocker martinis apparently exist](http://www.completecocktails.com/Drinks/AppleknockerMartini.aspx#.Ws45I4huaiM), consisting of lime vodka and apple juice or cider.

Comment: yes, you got it

Answer (score 6):

I guess the answer is

> Apprentice

*My first is fruit,*

> **app** refers to apple, I suppose?

*last is knuckle substitute,*

> Beaten by knuckles can be hurt, yet **ice** may also do the trick.

*middle one is space so small,*

> Usually a **rent** place can't be big...

*but I am ignorant overall.*

> An apprentice is ignorant of the technique that he/she is going to learn.

Comment: If it doesn;t fit use a bigger mallet?

Comment: sorry, not the word I am looking for, oh and hurting anyone is a no-no (going in the wrong direction there)

Comment: @smriti I get it, so rot13(gur jbeq "xahpxyr" vf abg fgnaq sbe fbzr xvaq bs jrncba), isn't it?

Comment: @ShaneHsu, could be......could be

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be

> Apple Genius

My first is fruit

> Apple

last is knuckle substitute

> Genius, a substitute for strength, punches, knuckle-busters

middle one is space so small,

> There's a space in between

but I am ignorant overall.

> A bit condescending and generalising, agreed, but they haven't all been as genius as their name suggests, and OP may have met some bad ones..

Comment: +1 but, sorry not the right one, it IS one word.

Answer (score 2):

> "App-Void-Dice"; say it fast "avoidance"

My first is fruit,

> App, per Shane Hsu's and OnlyF's prior answers

last is knuckle substitute,

> Roman soldiers made their dice with sheep knuckle bones

middle one is space so small,

> the void, a space so small

but I am ignorant overall

> when you practice avoidance, you don't learn very much, and probably slur pronunciations too

Comment: Good answer but unfortunately not what I was looking for. Answer consists of them together, without any omission

Answer (score 1):

Since they got the first part right, here's a partial thought (which I feel is incorrect):

> Appointer?
> App for apple
> 'pointer' finger
> a point is very small
> overall...no idea

Comment: Good answer but unfortunately not what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> Appendages

First

> **App** would stand for apple

Middle

> A **pen** is an enclosure for holding animals such as livestock or pets(which is usually small).

Last

> **Dages**, It was a name given to a person who carried a dagger(used in ancient times). Dagger can be knuckle substitute.

but I am ignorant overall.

> Appendage often describes body parts, either on humans or animals. If it's something that sticks out — like a finger, tail, or leg — chances are it can be called an appendage. ... In this sense, the word takes on a negative connotation: the appendage is not important.(ignorant).

Comment: God answer, +1, but not what I was looking for, and the word does not use shortcuts

Comment: I think my answer fits the riddle perfectly. Do you have hints which would be different from it?

Comment: yes, I will be uploading one in short time

Answer (score 0):

Is it?

> Appletini

My first is fruit,

> apple - already established.

last is knuckle substitute,

> a knuckle is a joint.  a knee (ni) is a joint.

middle one is space so small,

> plet aka [Plettenberg bay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plettenberg_Bay) - a small(ish) town in South Africa

or,

> tini (teeny) small

but I am ignorant overall.

> You can get pretty ignorant of what you did after having a couple.  Also some might consider an appletini is a rather ignorant drink.

Superhero hint

> I have no idea